# Let $a_n = d(p_n,p_{n+1})$ for $n \in\mathbb{N}$ . Show that if the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = d({p_n},{p_{n+1}})$ for $n \in\mathbb{N}$ .  Show that if the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$  converges, then ${p_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: People, be careful with your edits!

Comment: I fixed the title.

Comment: Some of your thoughts about the problem would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the triangle inequality $$d(p_n,p_m)\leqslant \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} d(p_k,p_{k+1})$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. As $\sum a_n<\infty$, then there exists an $n_0$, such that $\sum_{n\ge n_0}a_n<\varepsilon$. Now let $m,n\ge n_0$, $m\ge n$. Then
$$
d(p_m,p_n)\le d(p_n,p_{n+1})+\cdots+d(p_{m-1},p_m) =a_n+\cdots+a_{m-1}\le \sum_{k\ge n_0}a_k
<\varepsilon.
$$